# Dynamic JS result doesn't load in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, innerhtml

I made a quote calculator in plain JS on Codepen, and was happy with the results.

Now, I'm trying to reuse this calculator - which worked fine - within my Vue.js project. But for some reason, the console hits me with this error, when I try to use the calculator:

[image]

I suspect it's the swap from plain JS to Vue that's messing something up, but could anyone here enligthen me as to what it is I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance

```
 <form>
  <div class="calculator-variables">
   <input type="text" min="0" max="100" id="churnRate" onchange="CalculateEstimate();" />
   <input type="text" min="0" max="100" id="invoulentaryChurn" onchange="CalculateEstimate();" />
   <input type="text" id="contributionMargin" onchange="CalculateEstimate();" />
   <output id="output">0</output>
   <input id="customerNumber" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="3000" step="100" onchange="CalculateEstimate(); sliderChange(this.value);" />
   <div class="range"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

hej

min far
er
en mand

```
<script>
 export default {
  name: "calculator",
  methods: {
    CalculateEstimate: function () {
      var b1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("churnRate").value);
      var b2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("invoulentaryChurn").value);
      var b3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("contributionMargin").value);
      var b4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("customerNumber").value);

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        (1 / (b1 / 100)) * b3 * (b4 * (b2 / 100)) * 12 * 0.5 +
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Have you already checked the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#method-handlers) for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why this code is not looks like in `vue.js` format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "onchange" attribute in the input tag cannot directly access a Vue method. Instead of onchange, use the v-on:change Event Handler to bind your inputs with your Vue methods. (More information about event handlers here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html?redirect=true)

Here's what you could write:

```
<input type="text" min="0" max="100" id="churnRate" v-on:change="CalculateEstimate()" />
<input type="text" min="0" max="100" id="invoulentaryChurn" v-on:change="CalculateEstimate()" />
<input type="text" id="contributionMargin" v-on:change="CalculateEstimate()" />
```

A shorthand version for `v-on:change` is `@change`. Both work the same.

Also it looks like your CalculateEstimate equation seems to be incomplete, just to let you know ;)

Comment: That's it! What a wonderfull solution, and the response time, wow! Thanks a ton, really appreciated! :)